# Why does roslyn give warning CS8002 instead of error CS1577 for unsigned references?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm working on a little project in VS2015 for the company I work for, and as a company policy, all assemblies we produce must be signed.

I found a little odd behavior when I added a dependency to a nuget package that contained an unsigned assembly. When building the project with [vs2015](/questions/tagged/vs2015), I get the warning:

> CSC : warning CS8002: Referenced assembly 'XXX, Version=A.B.C.D, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have a strong name.

That seemed strange when I first saw it, because I remembered that it didn't compile in VS2013 or earlier. In fact, I get the following error when building the same project in [vs2013](/questions/tagged/vs2013):

> CSC : error CS1577: Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'XXX' does not have a strong name.

I thought that maybe something had changed in the runtime, and this was now supported. I couldn't be more wrong. When running my code built with warnings in VS2015, I now get a runtime error. The exact exception I get is a `FileLoadException` with message

> Could not load file or assembly 'XXX, Version=A.B.C.D, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

I'm aware that there are some nuget packages out there that sign any unsigned dependency before build (like [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nivot.StrongNaming/), or [this other](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Brutal.Dev.StrongNameSigner/), or [this last one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StrongNamer/)).

My questions here are: Is there any way that referencing an unsigned assembly from a signed one could work, and I'm missing something? If not, why then this is now a compiler warning, if it's going to give a runtime error later?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There seems to be a GitHub issue open for this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/399 It looks like the issue was closed though with the fix making it into 1.0 RC2, are you working from an older RC?

Comment: I'm with the RTM version of VS2015. I don't think the issue you pointed out is about the same issue I have. The one you pointed out seems to be that roslyn incorrectly reported that there was a reference to an unsigned assembly, when in fact the referenced assembly was signed.

Comment: I missed one very important detail in my answer rendering it pretty much useless: the reference from within your own project actually records the fact that the assembly is unsigned. My answer was about a project reference to a signed assembly, but building against an unsigned assembly, which is a different scenario. I deleted my answer, and I'm very curious to see if someone else can give you a good answer.

Comment: We're tracking this question at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7277

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing unsigned assembly from signed is ok on some platforms (like CoreCLR). The compiler doesn't know what platform are you going to run on hence it no longer reports an error. We still report a warning since you might run into problems as you did on Desktop CLR.